# Jquery trigger only on small window

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have simple toggle div. I need on the big screens paragraph `content` open when hover, and on the small screens when click. I try to do like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="headline">Headline exaple</div>
    <p class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae quia nulla, rem harum, minima sint assumenda perferendis cupiditate rerum corporis obcaecati, quam natus repudiandae veniam dolor. Maiores commodi sequi, esse.
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.headline {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.headline:hover + .content {
    display: block;
}

.content {
    padding: 5px;
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var isSmallWindow;
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    isSmallWindow = $(this).width() < 768;
});

$('.headline').on('click', function() {
    if (isSmallWindow) {
        $('.content').slideToggle(300);
    }
});
```

But it does not work properly. When I change the window size `content` is still open when hover. I clicked on the `headline` and when I return window of its original position, then hover not working. How to solves this problem?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9a1n8xtw/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: The hover behaviour is controlled by css, it will always occur no matter what size the screen is

Comment: You could add a class via js and if its present prevent the hover in css.

Comment: Remove your css in hover and do it in jquery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the `:hover` pseudo on your CSS. While this exists, the behaviour persists.

You can add a `.small-window` class to your `<html>` tag and control it with that.

https://jsfiddle.net/9a1n8xtw/4/

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    isSmallWindow = $(this).width() < 768;
    if(isSmallWindow) {
        $('html').addClass('small-window');
    }else {
        $('html').removeClass('small-window');
    }
});
```

And the css

```
html:not(.small-window) .headline:hover + .content {
    display: block;
}
```

### UPDATE

To avoid style overriding by `slideToggle()` you can remove style property like this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    isSmallWindow = $(this).width() < 768;
    if(isSmallWindow) {
        $('html').addClass('small-window');
    }else {
        $('html').removeClass('small-window');
    }
    $('.content').attr('style', false);
});
```

See the updated fiddle working fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/9a1n8xtw/7/

Comment: If you click on a title on small screens, while at large will not work Hover

Comment: I don't understand your comment. This solution works fine. Explain better what you need if this don't fit with your problem

Comment: It works in small screen with click, and with hover in large screens. I don't know what you are trying to tell us,...

Comment: Make a small screen browser and click on the headline. Everything works well! But if the return size back then hover does not work

Comment: Yes, it works. The only way that doesn't works is in onload page, because you have the calcs in the resize event. But it works. Try in the window of the fiddle. You can resize the preview view and see it works. Tested on Firefox 42

Comment: Ok, now I'm understand you. The problem is that `slideToggle()` is injecting the style property and it rewrites your css by priority. The way to workaround is putting `$('.content').attr('style', false);` as in the updated fiddle. I update my answer